# How do I unit test my implementation of javax.naming.Referenceable?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, jms, jndi

I'm developing a JMS provider to spec, and it requires that certain objects implement [Referenceable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/Referenceable.html).  I've implemented getReference() on my JMS ConnectionFactory, and I've created an [object factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/spi/ObjectFactory.html) to convert the References to objects.  I am trying to figure out an effective way to unit test.

Spring's SimpleNamingContext does not fit the bill:

```
Context ctx = new SimpleNamingContext();
ctx.bind("testFactory", connFactory);
ConnectionFactory testConnFactory = (ConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("testFactory");
Assert.assertEquals(connFactor, testConnFactory);
```

It gives me a false positive because SimpleNamingContext is a mock object.  The objects are identical and *neither getReference nor my object factory gets called*.

I've looked into possibly wiring up a Jetty server to test, but this might be a tad more than I need here.

Ideally, I'm looking for a simple Context class I can wire straight into like the example above that will actually execute my JNDI-specific methods behind the scenes.  Short of that, I'll take other recommendations on how to unit test this.

I'm using the Java [Referenceable Objects and References](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/objects/storing/reference.html) tutorials for defining how they should be implemented.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I'm not sure this is relevant, but here is the [object factory](https://github.com/carterpage/nevado/blob/master/src/main/java/org/skyscreamer/nevado/jms/resource/NevadoReferencableFactory.java), and here is the [Referenceable.getReference()](https://github.com/carterpage/nevado/blob/master/src/main/java/org/skyscreamer/nevado/jms/NevadoConnectionFactory.java#L131) implementation that I'm trying to test.

CONCLUSION: Per Nicholas' advice below I used RefFSContextFactory.  Here was the code I used to generate the context in my JUnit test:

```
@Rule public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

private Context getContext() throws MalformedURLException, NamingException {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
        "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, folder.getRoot().toURI().toURL().toString());
    Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
    Assert.assertNotNull(ctx);
    return ctx;
}
```

Full source code for now-working test class is [here](https://github.com/carterpage/nevado/blob/master/nevado-jms/src/test/java/org/skyscreamer/nevado/jms/resource/ReferencableTest.java).

Comment: Are you testing if the SimpleNamingContext() is functioning or is this part of your unit test?

Comment: I'm testing getReference() and my implementation of a JNDI object factory.  I tried using SimpleNamingContext(), but since it's a mock object it doesn't actually hit the real JNDI hooks.

Comment: Make sure you incorporate thread context classloaders into your test suite. The last time I worked on a JNDI SPI, context classloaders comprised most of the complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the File System Context Provider. Here's one [source for the jar](https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/central-proxy/content/com/sun/messaging/mq/fscontext/4.5.1-b03/fscontext-4.5.1-b03.jar). There's an example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/getStarted/examples/naming.html).

Comment: Winner, winner chicken dinner!  Thanks!